# Error while running stubby4node using Gulp

Tags: gulp

I am trying to setup [Stubby Server](https://github.com/mrak/stubby4node) in my JavaScript environment and I am getting the error below.

The relevant part of my Gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('stubby', function(cb) {
    var options = {
        callback: function (server, options) {
            server.get(1, function (err, endpoint) {
                if (!err)
                    console.log(endpoint);
            });
        },
        stubs: 8000,
        tls: 8443,
        admin: 8010,
        files: [
            '*.*'
        ]
    };
    stubby(options, cb);
});
```

The error:

```
[12:15:03] Starting 'stubby'...
[12:15:03] 'stubby' errored after 17 ms
[12:15:03] Error: Missing error message
    at new PluginError (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\gulp-util\lib\PluginError.js:73:28)
    at readJSON (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\gulp-stubby-server\index.js:90:15)
    at C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\gulp-stubby-server\index.js:149:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at stubbyPlugin (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\gulp-stubby-server\index.js:136:12)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\gulpfile.js:54:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\myproject\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Searching the `gulp-stubby-server` codebase for `PluginError` yields the follow snippet:](https://github.com/felixzapata/gulp-stubby-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PluginError)

```
function readJSON(filepath, options) {
    var src = fs.readFileSync(filepath, options),
        result;
    if (!options.mute) {
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow('Parsing ' + filepath + '...'));
    }
    try {
        result = JSON.parse(src);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        throw new gutil.PluginError(PLUGIN_NAME, 'Unable to parse "' + filepath + '" file (' + e.message + ').', e);
    }
}
```

— [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/felixzapata/gulp-stubby-server/blob/dcdcc5144e557366e3ffb61e6effcc94a0769e8b/index.js#L80-L92)

You can tell this is the likely culprit because of the stack trace you see, where the `PluginError` is coming from `readJSON`.

#### The issue

Take note of the `catch` block. This is caused by one of the files matching your glob (`*.*`) not being a valid JSON file.

#### To fix

1. Ensure you are using the newest version of `gulp-stubby-server`
2. Ensure that you are using the correct glob (that is, do you really mean `*.*`)
3. Ensure that all the files in the current working directory are valid JSON files

Comment: Thanks Whymarrh! It was an issue with the gulp-stubby-server version I was using. I upgraded to latest and issue got resolved. Strangely we are using the same version at my work place and it works there.